# Interface-like definition in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, c++

I'm writing a new Arduino project that uses an 16x2 LCD Crystal Display with a KeyShield. I would like to construct a menu structure in which the user can navigate using the buttons.

I'm new to Arduino but I do have 5 yrs experience in C#. What I would like to do is the following:

Define an interface called `Screen` and inherit each Screen from it such as `LanguageScreen`, `TurnOffAfterScreen`, `MainScreen`, etc. Each specialized Screen implements a method called `drawScreen` that will take care of the screen content.

Now I would like to have a class named `ScreenController` that handles the navigation between the Screens. In this class I'd like to store the screens in an array `Screen screens[3]`.

When user presses the `Select` button on the KeyShield the Controller would call the next Screen's `drawScreen` method something like this:

```
void showNextScreen()
{
   currentScreen++;
   screens[currentScreen]->drawScreen();
}
```

Is this possible to do in an Arduino project? Am I expecting too much? :)

Comment: There’s no particular reason why this cannot be made to work. However, in C++, `Screen` would have to be an (abstract) base class, and your array would have to be `Screen * screens[3]`.

Comment: Sounds cool! Can you post some code as well?

Comment: I’ve added some code in an answer below. This is really straightforward C++ code with little Arduino specific relevance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Screen {
public:
   virtual void drawScreen() = 0;  // Needs to be implemented by each subclass

   virtual ~Screen() {}            // Destructor
};

class LanguageScreen : public Screen {
public:
   virtual void drawScreen();
};

class MainScreen : public Screen {
public:
   virtual void drawScreen();
};

void LanguageScreen::drawScreen() {
   // Draw language screen
}

void MainScreen::drawScreen() {
   // Draw main screen
}

MainScreen     mainScreen;
LanguageScreen languageScreen;
Screen *const  screens[2]   = {&mainScreen, &languageScreen};
int            currenScreen = 0;
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to avoid calling new in a microcontroller example.  Declare them as statics/globals and then use their addresses.

Comment: Good point, @walrii. I’ve revised the code to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was quite helpful. Now I have good menu structure using well defined OOP code :)

Comment: I'm coming from PHP and I'm expecting to get an error message if I don't implement a method in a class that's based on an interface.

`class Screen {
public:
   virtual void drawScreen() = 0;  // Needs to be implemented by each subclass

   virtual ~Screen() {}            // Destructor
};

class LanguageScreen : public Screen {
// I didn't define the void drawScreen();
};`

So I actually want to get a message that the method drawScreen() is missing in the class LanguageScreen since it implements the "interface" class Screen. Or is this different to PHP?

Comment: @alve89 if you try this in C++, you will find that the `= 0;` in the original declaration will also guarantee an error message if you try to use a subclass that does not implement `drawScreen`. The difference is that you can inherit over multiple levels, and only one of them needs to implement the method.

Comment: @microtherion Thanks! I tried and it worked. The problem was that I expected the error message to be shown on compiling without instantiate the object, but the error is thrown when the object is defined only. But now I know, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

C++ using classes on a microcontroller with limited memory is generally not considered to be a viable development strategy. There are literally limitless ways that you can construct a "menu system" on a display without having to resort to resource intensive OOP programming style.

**Edit:**
I am amazed at the reader reaction to putting a lot of down votes to my answer. I can tell you that with over 30 years of experience in developing code and firmware solutions for microcontrollers of many sorts that there is truth to the statement of my answer. There are loads of applications using low performance MCUs (in comparison to their big brothers in PCs and the like) where the program at times even needs to be coded in assembly language to get the job done in a efficient and low latency way.

Comment: It won't be that big project so I'm not afraid of running out of memory. I prefer OOP to spagetti code.

Comment: @papaiatis - A menu system can be coded in nice clean programming style in C or even Assembly language without it turning into spagetti code. The latter mess of code usually results when you try to program something up by the seat of the pants without taking the time to do a full architectural design of the intended functionality tp be developed.

Comment: You might be right I have no doubt. But I'm still rather interested in the OOP way.

Comment: Using C++ classes is viable on a microcontroller as long as you limit the amount of memory a giving class can use. Creating dynamic menus could be problematic if you are persisting state, but if you are only providing rendering and selection functionality you should be OK. You will also have to watch how much code space you are using by creating this convenient object model as these kind of constructs can take up significant space. That is all.

Comment: The Arduino I/O library is in fact a very conventional OOP design, constructed around a set of classes with virtual methods. There is little in OOP programming style which is inherently “resource intensive”.

Comment: I concur - given the limited memory on these puppies, you are right on the money with your answer. I also dislike the buttons on these LCD shields, as they use variable resistance for each button through an analog input, and the shield I have gives some wildly different values each time.

Comment: +1 - I agree with a caveat. Some language features are more expensive than others, however, and a limited subset can be quite useful. The merged listing can be your friend here. OTOH, if you know you'll be pushing hard against the limits of the hardware and will probably have to optimize, you'll be better off starting out with the most hardware-efficient development techniques you can afford the human resources and development time for - which is to say, put off optimizing as long as you can, but prepare to make as easy on yourself as you can.

Comment: Judging by the way people use Arduino I am pretty sure running a light dimmer with OOP code wont be a memory issue. However when you need to squeeze a lot out of a little device well OOP is Out Of Practical value instead of Object Oriented Programming. Try a class library on a Amtel Tiny for example. Upvoted this as I think this answer has a very valid point.